# Can I get the value of the grouped column in groupby apply?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda

Can I get the value of grouped column in apply in pandas groupby?
For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('bird', 389.0),
                   ('bird', 24.0),
                   ('mammal', 80.5),
                   ('mammal', np.nan)],
                  index=['falcon', 'parrot', 'lion', 'monkey'],
                  columns=('class', 'max_speed'))
```

I used group by for column `class` and want to use the value of `class` in x `df.groupby('class').apply(lambda x: ??)`

Comment: Waht is expected ouput? What means `and want to use the value of class in x `

Comment: I mean can i use value of group in lambda function

Comment: What is value of group? index, another column? Can you add how looks final df?

Comment: the value is values of column, in this case it's 'bird' or 'mammal'. I want to get value 'mammal' or 'bird' from x

Comment: Super, so how looks final DataFrame? Solution bellow working like need?

Comment: Yes, the solution below's exactly what i need, thank you! I use another dataset. And it uses this value to get a value from dict by key, which is a x.name. And then I filter dataset by value from dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use `x.name`:

```
print (df.groupby('class').apply(lambda x: x.name))
class
bird        bird
mammal    mammal
dtype: object
```